# asp.menu fixed positioning issue with submenu CSS

Tags: css

Morning,

Hopefully someone can assit, I have an asp.menu with custom CSS, the main menu is FIXED, but the sub menu refuses to follow once scrolled, I mean the main menu scrolls fine but sub menu still populates at the top and not relative to the main menu.(after scrolling, if not scrolled the sub menu populates next to the relative option, as soon as scrolled its a mess.)

Sure its something small, I have tried to set the  (.primaryDynamicMenu) to fixed as well to no avail.

Here is my CSS, please advise if any of my other code is necessary:

```
.primaryStaticMenu
{
   background-color: transparent;
   left: -10px;
   top:30%;
   position:fixed;
   margin-top: -2.5em;
   text-align:left !important;
}
.primaryStaticMenuItem
{
   width:10em;
   background-color: #f7f2ea; 
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #efefef #aaab9c #ccc #efefef; 
   border-style: solid;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
   color: #777777;
   text-align:left !important;


}
.primaryStaticHover
{
   color: #800000;
   background: #f0e7d7;
   text-align:left !important;
}

.primaryDynamicMenu
{   
   background-color: #f7f2ea;               
   border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
   text-align:left !important;
   width:13em;
   position:fixed
}  
.primaryDynamicMenuItem
{
   width: 13em;
   background-color: #f7f2ea; 
   color: #777;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #f7f2ea #aaab9c #f7f2ea #efefef;  
   border-style: solid; 
   text-align:left !important;
}    
.primaryDynamicHover
{
   color: #800000;
   background: #f0e7d7;
   text-align:left !important;
}            

.secondaryLevelOne
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   width: 13em; 
   height: 30px;
   text-align:left !important;
}
.secondaryLevelTwo
{
   background: #FAFBFB;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
   text-align:left !important;
   width: 13em;  
}
.secondaryStaticHover
{
   color: #800000;
   text-align:left !important;
}
```

HTML(Added):

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.vb" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/menu43/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style3
        {
            width: 1000px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        .style4
        {
            text-align: center;
            width: 1000px;
        }
        .style6
        {
            width: 229px;
        }
        .style14
        {
            width: 128px;
        }
        .style15
        {
            width: 200px;
        }
        .style16
        {
            width: 251px;
        }
        #form1
        {
            height: 268px;
            width: 1004px;
        }
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 251px;
            height: 37px;
        }
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 229px;
            height: 37px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            height: 37px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            width: 321px;
            height: 37px;
        }

.primaryStaticMenu
{
   background-color: transparent;
   left: -10px;
   top:30%;
   position:fixed;
   margin-top: -2.5em;
   text-align:left !important;
}
.primaryStaticMenuItem
{
   width:10em;
   background-color: #f7f2ea; 
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #efefef #aaab9c #ccc #efefef; 
   border-style: solid;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
   color: #777777;
   text-align:left !important;


}
.primaryStaticHover
{
   color: #800000;
   background: #f0e7d7;
   text-align:left !important;
}

.primaryDynamicMenu
{   
   background-color: #f7f2ea;               
   border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
   text-align:left !important;
   width:13em;
}  
.primaryDynamicMenuItem
{
   width: 13em;
   background-color: #f7f2ea; 
   color: #777;
   padding: 0.5em 0 0.5em 1em;
   border-width: 1px;
   border-color: #f7f2ea #aaab9c #f7f2ea #efefef;  
   border-style: solid; 
   text-align:left !important;
}    
.primaryDynamicHover
{
   color: #800000;
   background: #f0e7d7;
   text-align:left !important;
}            

.secondaryLevelOne
{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   margin: 1.5em 0 0 0;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   width: 13em; 
   height: 30px;
   text-align:left !important;
}
.secondaryLevelTwo
{
   background: #FAFBFB;
   padding: 5px 0 5px 5px;
   text-align:left !important;
   width: 13em;  
}
.secondaryStaticHover
{
   color: #800000;
   text-align:left !important;
}


    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" title="" 
    style="margin: 0px; border: thick outset #800000;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="style14">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="XX-Large" 
                                ForeColor="Maroon" style="text-align: center; font-size: XX-Large;" 
                                Text="Legal" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                            <br />
                        </td>
            <td class="style4">
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/GVDM.png" 
                    Height="93px" Width="243px" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style14" 

                style="border-bottom-style: outset; border-bottom-width: thick; border-color: #800000">
                &nbsp;</td>
            <td class="style3">
                <table style="border-color: #800000; width:100%; border-bottom-style: outset; border-bottom-width: thick;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
                                ForeColor="Maroon" style="text-align: left; font-size: medium;" 
                                Text="UserName" Width="100%" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style5">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
                                ForeColor="Maroon" style="text-align: left; font-size: medium;" 
                                Text="Department" Width="100%" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="auto-style3" style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager3" runat="server">
                            </asp:ScriptManager>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right" class="auto-style4">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" 
                                ForeColor="Maroon" style="text-align: left" Text="Date" Font-Names="Arial"></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Menu ID="Menu1"  runat="server" Orientation="Vertical" > 
                    <DynamicHoverStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicHover" />
                    <DynamicMenuItemStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicMenuItem" />
                    <DynamicMenuStyle CssClass="primaryDynamicMenu" />
                    <DynamicSelectedStyle CssClass="" />
                    <StaticHoverStyle CssClass="primaryStaticHover" />
                    <StaticMenuItemStyle CssClass="primaryStaticMenuItem" />
                    <StaticMenuStyle CssClass="primaryStaticMenu" />
                    <StaticSelectedStyle CssClass="" />
                    <Items>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/EmployeeDashboard.aspx" Text="Dashboard" Value="Dashboard"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Workflow" Value="Workflow">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/BookOutFilesToEmployee.aspx" Text="Book Out Files" Value="Book Out Files"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/FilesWorkflowHistory.aspx" Text="File History" Value="File History"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/MoveProblemFiles.aspx" Text="Move Problem Files" Value="Move Problem Files"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Matters.aspx" Text="Matters" Value="Matters"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/BulkActions.aspx" Text="Bulk Actions" Value="Bulk Actions"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/DebitOrders.aspx" Text="Debit Orders" Value="Debit Orders"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtDetails.aspx" Text="Court Details" Value="Court Details"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Accounting" Value="Accounting">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Bankstatement.aspx" Text="Bank Statement" Value="Bank Statement"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/BankstatementImport.aspx" Text="Bank Statment Import" Value="Bank Statment Import"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Find Unknown" Value="Find Unknown" NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/FindUnknown.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Reports" Value="Reports">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/BalanceAssessment.aspx" Text="Balance Assessment" Value="Balance Assessment"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Clients" Value="Clients">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Nimble" Value="Nimble">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/NimbleActionsFile.aspx" Text="Actions File" Value="Actions File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/NimbleFinancialFile.aspx" Text="Nimble Financial File" Value="Nimble Financial File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Autopage" Value="Autopage">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/AutopageStatusFile.aspx" Text="Status File" Value="Status File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="HTN" Value="HTN">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/HTNFinancialFile.aspx" Text="Financial File" Value="Financial File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/HTNStatusFile.aspx" Text="Status File" Value="Status File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/HTNArrangementFile.aspx" Text="Arrangement File" Value="Arrangement File"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Courts" Value="Courts">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtProcessList.aspx" Text="Court Process List" Value="Court Process List"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Section129NoticeData.aspx" Text="Section 129 Notice Data" Value="Section 129 Notice Data"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Setup" Value="Setup">
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Accounting" Value="Accounting">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/BankstatementSplitRules.aspx" Text="Bank Statement Split Rules" Value="Bank Statement Split Rules"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Clients" Value="Clients">
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Clients" Value="Clients" NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Clients.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Client Contracts" Value="Client Contracts" NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/ClientContracts.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Client Status Mapping" Value="Client Status Mapping">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/PreLegalClientStatusMapping.aspx" Text="PreLegal Mapping" Value="PreLegal Mapping"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/NelspruitLiveClientStatusMapping.aspx" Text="NelspruitLive Mapping" Value="NelspruitLive Mapping"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/LegalClientStatusMapping.aspx" Text="Legal Mapping" Value="Legal Mapping"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Courts" Value="Courts">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Courts.aspx" Text="Courts" Value="Courts"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtClerks.aspx" Text="Court Clerks" Value="Court Clerks"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtCorrespondents.aspx" Text="Court Correspondents" Value="Court Correspondents"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtMagistrates.aspx" Text="Court Magistrates" Value="Court Magistrates"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtProcessCourtLinks.aspx" Text="Court Process Court Links" Value="Court Process Court Links"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/CourtProcessDocumentLinks.aspx" Text="Court Process Document Links" Value="Court Process Document Links"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/DocumentTypes.aspx" Text="Document Types" Value="Document Types"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/EmployerEmployeeLinks.aspx" Text="Employer Employee Links" Value="Employer Employee Links"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Geography" Value="Geography">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Provinces.aspx" Text="Provinces" Value="Provinces"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Towns.aspx" Text="Towns" Value="Towns"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/Districts.aspx" Text="Districts" Value="Districts"></asp:MenuItem>
                            </asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/MasterContentPages/LegalSuiteImport.aspx" Text="Legal Import" Value="Legal Import"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Bulk Matching" Value="Bulk Matching">
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/NonMasterContentPages/IdentityNumberMatch.aspx" Text="Identity Numbers" Value="Identity Numbers"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/NonMasterContentPages/BeenToLegalMatch.aspx" Text="Been To Legal Status" Value="Been To Legal Status"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </asp:MenuItem>
                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </td>
            <td class="style3" style="vertical-align: top">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post DOM also for better understanding

Comment: Not sure what that all includes? (DOM?)

Comment: We need the HTML as well...in a [mcve].

Comment: Please just ignore line:                                                                                 <link href="Styles/menu43/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Can anyone please assist?

Comment: Do you need more info?

Comment: Anyone? Anyone?

Comment: Why is no one helping me here?